# Why can I not add a animation to a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, calayer, catransition

Im trying to add a animation to a UIImageView, but it always fails. Why? Here is the code:

```
        //(…)
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
        animationImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:newImage];
        [self.view addSubview:animationImage];

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setDuration:0.35];
        [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        animation.type = @"pageCurl";
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.endProgress = 0.58;
        [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
        [[animationImage layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

insteaad of:

```
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

Comment: Doens´t work. The strange thing is that my code works with self.view layer, but not with animationImage layer…

Comment: I must be missing something then, because UIImageView inherits from UIView, so you should be able to add animations to its layer.

Comment: @Flocked : dear try `animationImage.layer` and accept this answer as it helped me too.. :)